How can I disable this backup? Ubuntu 23.10
After turning on my system, a backup message appears
How can I disable this backup?
my OS : Ubuntu 23.10
kernel : 6.5.0-28-generic


Assuming you have Deja-Dup aka Backups installed, start it.
Click the three bar menu in the program header and select Preferences.
Click General at the top of the window that pops up.
Scroll down to the heading Schedule and turn off Back up Automatically.
